# How to substitute for matching delimiters in vi?

Tags: vim, vi, replace, delimiter

I have some text which has matched delimiters (in this case, curly braces, and the text happens to be LaTeX, which is only incidental):

```
\nb{\vec{n},\vec{y}} \in \vec{z}
```

What I'd like to do is globally replace `\nb{...}` with `(...)`, while respecting the nesting of delimiters. I.e., the result should be

```
(\vec{n},\vec{y}) \in \vec{z}
```

and not

```
(\vec{n},\vec{y}} \in \vec{z)
```

which is what would be produced by `:%s/\\nb{\(.*\)}/(\1)/g`. Standard regular expressions can't handle matched delimiters, so I wasn't expecting this way to work. Is there some vi-specific trick I can use to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the following `:global` command.

```
:g/\\nb{/norm!/^M%r)[{r(dF\\
```

Type `^M` as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: This deletes every WORD on the line before the `\nb`, which isn't correct. It looks like `dB` should be `d2b` or `dF\\ ` instead.

Comment: @uckelman:  You are right, I have made a mistake at the last moment.  Initially (as it can be seen in the revision history), that delete command was `d3h`, but I decided that it is better not to make the deletion dependent on the length of the command (which could be easily changed in `:g` pattern), and I went for the simple `dB` that deletes too much when there is a text chock-a-block before `\nb`.

Comment: +1 for using `:g//` and `[{`. The surround version would be a bit like this `:g/\\nb{/norm/^Mdt{cs{)`. Note: there is not `!` on `:norm`

Answer (score 3):

If you have [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) installed then the following should do the trick

```
:set nowrapscan
:let @q="/\\m\\\\nb{/e+1\<cr>cs{)dF\\@q"
gg@q
```

If you do not:

```
:set nowrapscan
let @q="/\\m\\\\nb{<cr>dt{yi{\"_ca{()\<esc>\"0P@q"
gg@q
```

Overview

Create a recursive macro that searches for `\nb{`, positions the cursor just inside the `{`, replace the `}{`'s with `()`'s.

Glory of Details

- `:set nowrapscan` this prevents searches from looping back around the file.
- `:let @q="..."` store our macro inside the `q` register
- `/\m\nb{/e+1` searches for `\nb{` and positions the cursor after the `{`
- `cs{)` the surround version will just change the surrounding `{` with `)`
- `@q` run the macro again
- Used `"` so must escape a few things so they work correctly.
- `gg@q` go to the top of the file and execute the macro in register `q`

The non surround version varies a bit here

- `yi{` copy the text inside `{`'s
- `"_ca{()<esc>` change the text inside and including the `{`'s and replace with `()`
- `"0P` paste what we just copied inside the `()`

Comment: Very good post. Haven't tested it but the approach with surround.vim was the same thing I immediately though of. +1

Comment: @Peter, @sehe:  Using `:global` command to repeat the change makes the whole thing much less verbose sometimes.

Comment: @ib: certainly does, but I do not know latex and do not know if there will there be multiple `\nb{`'s per line.

Comment: @Peter:  Agree.  Anyway, in case of multiple `\nb`s at line I would prefer to repeat a shorter global command. :-)

Comment: @ib: Although I have a special place in my heart for recursive macros, I must agree with you, multiple `:g//` would probably be nicer. :)

Comment: @Peter:  Recursive macro is a beautiful concept, indeed!  They are well suited to address this problem, as you have shown in this detailed answer.  +1